# Plain TeX: Wrong \folio for heading at top of page

Tags: page-breaking, plain-tex

I have the following chapter macro (uses code from Heiko Oberdiek):

```
\def\ChaptTocEntry#1#2{%
  \line{\hbox to1em{\hfil\bf#1}\hskip1em#2\leaderfill\folio}}
\def\ChaptWr#1{{%
  \let\folio\relax
  \edef\next{%
    \write0{\noexpand\ChaptTocEntry{\the\ChaptNo}{#1}}}\next}}
\def\Chapt#1{\advance\ChaptNo by1\SecNo=0%
  \vskip-\lastskip
  \bigskip\noindent{\bf\the\ChaptNo\hskip1em#1}\ChaptWr{#1}\par\nobreak\medskip
  \everypar={{\setbox0=\lastbox}\everypar={}}}
```

`\par\nobreak\medskip` is used to not allow page breaks between the heading and the following text. Although the TOC information is written (`\ChaptWr{#1}`) after the heading text is set (the `#1` before `\ChaptWr`) the wrong page number is used if the `\nobreak` causes the shift of the heading to the top of the next page.

If `\ChaptWr` is put later in the definition (after `\nobreak`) it allows page breaks itself. I don't know why since it does not contain anything which is output to the page (only to a file).

When I simplify the the heading macro to

```
\def\Chapt#1{%
  \bigskip\noindent{\folio\ #1}\par\nobreak\medskip
  \everypar={{\setbox0=\lastbox}\everypar={}}}
```

`\folio` is wrong for "shifted" headings (does still output the previous page number).

Comment: Either set `\folio` in the output routine (typical: header or footer line) or you need some kind of `\label`/`\ref` mechanism like the one in LaTeX.

Comment: I did set a new register: `\headline={\hfil\folio\hfil\global\PageNo=\pageno}` but this makes the problem even worse. I don't understand why `\folio` is correct in the page header but displayed wrong some vertical skip down in the page (and then correct again more lower in the page). How can I set \folio in the header?

Comment: When TeX typesets the paragraphs and sets the page number, it is *not* yet known, on which page the paragraph lines will be put (asynchronous output routine).

Comment: I had guest this meanwhile. Since I call the heading macro before that paragraph it means there is no way to get the correct page number for the TOC ... Is there a simple solution that other plain TeX users use in this case?

Comment: Next thing I need is indeed an index and cross references. So anyway I need something like `\label`/`\ref`. This can then be used for TOC too. I hope I find something helpfull in the TeXbook or its source. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Before you reinvent too many wheels, take a look at [eplain](http://ctan.org/pkg/eplain). It has already support for the table of contents and cross references.

Comment: You can be inspired by OPmac macros http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-e.html for plain TeX too.

Answer (score 2):

The description of the index implementation in the TeXbook (p. 423-424) provided a simple solution for the heading macro:

```
\newwrite\TocFh

\def\MkTocEnt{%
  \xdef\WrTocEnt{\write\TocFh{\line{\TocText\leaderfill
    \noexpand\number\pageno}}}\WrTocEnt}

\def\Chapt#1{\advance\ChaptNo by1 \SecNo=0
  \vskip-\lastskip
  \bigskip\noindent{\bf\the\ChaptNo\hskip1em#1}% output heading
  {\def\TocText{\hbox to1em{\hfil\bf\the\ChaptNo}\hskip1em#1}% output TOC data
    \let\next=\TocText\MkTocEnt}%
  \par\nobreak\medskip
  \everypar={{\setbox0=\lastbox}\everypar={}}}

\def\TOC{\input toc\immediate\openout\TocFh=toc}
```

(`\leaderfill` is something like `\hfil`, see TeXbook p. 223.)

This solution should work for index and cross references too.